# Cordova plugins for application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, batterymanager

Is there any mechanism to check the battery usage and network usage by a particular app on IOS. Do we have any Cordova plugin for these native features.

Answer (score 1):

For the battery usage you can use the Cordova Battery Status Plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status
```

For the network usage you can use Cordova Network Information Plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Both are standard plugins that are easy installs.

Comment: how much data and battery is being used by an app on the device and relay that back to the server.